# Array job with unknown task number

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub, torque

I would like to submit an array job on a cluster running SGE.
I know [how to use array jobs](http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto) with the `-t` option (for instance, `qsub -t 1-1000 somescript.sh`).

What if I don't know how many tasks I have to submit? The idea would be to use something like (**not working**):

`qsub -t 1- somescript.sh`

The submission would then go for all the `n` tasks, with unknown `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, open-ended arrays are not a built-in capability (nor can you add jobs to an array after initial submission).

I'm guessing about why you want to do this, but here's one idea for keeping track of a group of jobs like this: specify a shared name for the set of jobs, appending a counter.

So, for example, you'd include `-N myjob.<counter>` in your qsub (or add a #PBS script line for it):

`-N myjob.1
-N myjob.2
...
-N myjob.n`